# Using Methods Without Declaring them in the header

Tags: objective-c, oop

Recently I used an opaque pointer type in my code. I did this because I wanted to use c++ code in my obj c project without having to change every single file to .mm.

The way I use the c++ code is that I have a opaque pointer to my c++ code as a member of a .mm file. All the c++ is hidden in the implementation file.

In this class that contains my c++ I have a need to import an existing class "MyClass". I can import it fine in the implementation class but if I try to import it in the header I get c++ errors saying " ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'CARingBufferCPPWrapper' with no type".

I "can" just write the method in the .mm file and omit it from the header but I get a warning say that my .mm file may not respond to the method.

A lot of this is quite new to be so my terminology may be a little off. Let me know if I can clarify my question in any way.

TLDR: How can Class X Safely call a method in Class Y without the method being declared in Class Y header?

//My Header

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#define kBufferLength 5120

//#define "Myclass.h"
typedef struct ringbufferobj * RingBufferOBJ;


RingBufferOBJ newRingBufferOBJ();






@interface CARingBufferCPPWrapper : NSObject {

    RingBufferOBJ ringbuffer;
    NSThread  *producerthread;
    int duration;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSThread *producerthread;
@property(nonatomic)int duration;

//-(void)myclassfunction(MyClass *)classref

@end
```

//My Implementation .mm

```
#import "CARingBufferCPPWrapper.h"
#import "CARingBuffer.h"
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import "MyClass.h"

struct ringbufferobj
{
    CARingBuffer *ringbuffer;
    AudioBufferList *inputbuffer; 

    Float64 firstInputSampleTime;
    Float64 firstOutputSampleTime;
    Float64 inToOutSampleTimeOffset;





    BOOL producerthreadisrunning;
};

RingBufferOBJ newRingBufferOBJ(){
    RingBufferOBJ ringbuffer=(RingBufferOBJ)malloc(sizeof(struct ringbufferobj));

    return ringbuffer;
}


@implementation CARingBufferCPPWrapper
@synthesize producerthread;
@synthesize duration;


-(void)myclassfunction(MyClass *)classref
{

}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what your question is as I couldn't find anything that actually *asks* anything. (I even `Cmd+F`'d for "?"). I'm assuming however, that you're asking what you can do to get rid of that warning?

-If a method is declared above the method it is called it, there should be no warning. ( methods are compiled in order). To get rid of such a warning, you'd have to forward declare the method signature. (This is conventionally in the header, but I don't think there's anything stopping you just doing it at the top of your .m)

```
-(void) methodA {
    ..do something
    [self methodB]; //Warning here because the compiler has not yet seen methodB

}

-(void) method B {
    ..[self methodA]; //No warning, compiler knows what methodA is at this point. 
}
```

Comment: would this forward declaration allow the method to be called from other classes?

Comment: Unless it's in the header, it'll still produce the warning from other classes.

I _think_ it'll work fine at run-time though

Comment: Yeah it does work at runtime. I'm just not happy about having that warning there though. I clarified my question a little also